# Creating NSPredicate for external primary key

Tags: ios, subquery, nsfetchrequest

I looked at other questions and I saw glimpses of answers but none worked.

Here is my situation, I have two objects "Menu" and "Restaurant". Menu is where I have all menu items, and "Restaurant" is the name of different restaurants. Therefore:

Menu Object
- menuId
- name
- protein
- restaurantID (one-to-one)

Restaurant Object
- restaurantID (one-to-many)
- name

When the user gives me the restaurant name, I want to return the menu items. In SQL, it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM ZMENU WHERE zrestaurantId = (SELECT Z_PK FROM ZRESTAURANT WHERE zname="Starbucks")
```

I tried

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *e = [[model entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Restaurant"];
[request setEntity:e];
*NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(restaurant = (SUBQUERY(Restaurant, $x, $x.name like[cd] %@).@count))", restaurantName];
```

But I get the error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate SQL for predicate (restaurant == SUBQUERY(Restaurant, $x, $x.name LIKE[cd] "Starbucks").@count) (problem on RHS)'
```

Can someone please help? I want to avoid having to do two fetches (one for restaurant PK, other for the menu item), I believe there should be a more proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!!!!

Creating element was correct, just change the subquery to

NSEntityDescription *e = [[model entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Menu"];
        [request setEntity:e];

NSString restaurantName = @"Starbucks";

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(restaurantId, $x, $x.name == %@).@count != 0", restaurantName];
```

So the way subquery works is - you establish the object you want to get(Select on table) by setting the entity. Then on the predicate you use subquery on the field that references the external table. Then you specify the field in that table that you want to check, and that's it! I have no idea why there is a "count", but it works.

By the way per documentation, inside the subquery you can use %@ for ints or strings values you want to check, and you can use %K for field names you want to check. Pretty cool! :-D